# Sending values from JSP form to update database

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dao

I'm a beginner and I'm stuck with a part of my project. The fact is that I can't get the IdPatient from my JSP page to update my database. The goal is to get the id from the form and to set a column value with it.

Thanks in advance.

My Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/AddPatient.go")
  public ModelAndView AddPatient(
        HttpServletRequest pRequest,
        @RequestParam(value = "pIdPatient", required = false) String pIdPatient) {
    LOGGER.info("start");


    TicketAttenteBO ticket = searchIdPatient(pRequest, pIdPatient);
    ticket.setIdPatient("pIdPatient");  


    dao.updateTicket(ticket);

    pRequest.setAttribute("messageInfo", 
            "patient added" );      

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("welcome");

    return mv;

}


private TicketAttenteBO rechercherQueueParIdPatient(HttpServletRequest pRequest,String pIdPatient) {
    ************* I don’t know what to write here…

    return ticket;
}
```

My Dao implementation:

```
public ResultatBO updateTicket(TicketAttenteBO pInput) {
    ResultatBO result = new ResultatBO();
    result.setCodeRetour("OK");
    initConnexion();



        String template = "update queueclassic set statut='NON ADMIS' where idpatient='{1}';";
        String sql = template
                .replace("{1}", pInput.getIdPatient());

        connexion.executeThisUpdateQuery(sql);


    return result;
}
```

My jsp :

```
<div>
   Scan : <input name="pIdPatient" />   
</div>



<input type="submit" value="Insert"/>
```

Comment: Depends on what "rechercher" means in your language.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, `ticket.setIdPatient("pIdPatient");`
Here you are seting string "pIdPatient"  to ticket instead of its value.
I think it should be `ticket.setIdPatient(pIdPatient);`